# Connect to Python with Oracle

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have a Oracle server in other country.

Hostname: chqora34
Port: 1521
Service name: STARS5

When I try to download cx_Oracle, show the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 20, in <module>   File
"c:\users\jcuica~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-i05dlw\cx-Oracle\setup.py",
line 186, in <module>
    raise DistutilsSetupError(message) distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include
files in C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1
```

I do not have the client installed on my local machine because is not necessary.
Please, help me!

Comment: Why Oracle client is not needed?

Answer (score 0):

There **are** prereqs for cx_oracle. You need to install them beforehand.  Then also probably set ora_home or similar in your environment. Follow instructions.

Comment: I connect to an IP
Is necessary ORA_HOME?

Comment: For example in Java:
<connection-url>
             jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.0.187:1521:STARS53
</connection-url>

Comment: You need the oracle client software.  Cx_oracle doesnt even install without it. Thats your error.  But then Ora_home is the environment setting where you indicate the directory path where you've installed oracle, on your machine.  Read the instructions carefully. Then once oracle and cx_racle are both installed, you need a connection string. With IP or hostname, either work.

Comment: The problem was solved, i installed:

Oracle administrator and config tnsnames.ora  and 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Thanks guys!!...